# Get data of html table from a website in android using Jsoup library,

Tags: java, android, html, jsoup, html-parsing

I am working on an app where I am parsing some data from one or two websites. Luckily I did it for some of my targeted data but not. Now that I am using Jsoup for parsing the data from a website I used same jsoup format to get data of phase 2 as I did for phase 1 of my app but this time nothing is fetching arraylist showing up blank. I checked both HTML codes and there is a bit of difference in both.

In my phase1 i parsed the table using it's class and then i get the respective  of  that table. In the 2nd phase, the format of table and its tr & tds are different so i am struggling to figure it out. I am posting the html code from which i want to get data.

```html
<div class="view-content">
  <table class="views-table cols-3">
    <thead>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="odd views-row-first views-row-last">
        <td class="views-field views-field-counter">
          1 </td>
        <td class="views-field views-field-body">
          <p>some text here</p>
        </td>
        <td class="views-field views-field-field-notif-pdf">
          <a href="https://someurl.pdf" target="_blank"></a> Size :- 1.85 MB, Language:- English</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

I want the data inside above table tag and i am having problems to figure it out how it will be done with all classes in tr and td. Any help or suggestion will be highly appreciated..

THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

You can use selectors in Jsoup:

```
 File input = new File("path_to_html/test.html");
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
///select table body
        Element tbody = doc.select("tbody").first();
```

other examples at:

https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax